# Correct way to declare an image field, sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build and app with flask, I have seen some tutorial and books and some code[1] they explain how to declare integers and string for the database setup. However, they do not explain how to store images. I am very confused now I though the natural way to store images was on a database, but reading some documentation on the flask site[2] the filesystem is the place to store images. I just make a first assumption reading a flask development book that a declaration with largeBinary would be the correct one, but this is just my guess as you can see in the code below. can somebody help me to figure this out? if what I ask is not clear please let me know.

```
Class User(Base):
    __table__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name  Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    email =  Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    image = Column(LargeBinary, nullable = True)
```

[1]https://github.com/lobrown/Full-Stack-Foundations/blob/master/Lesson_1/database_setup.py
[2]http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: I'm just in the database design step,  I have to figure out how to insert and retrieve the data.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Linluk, Please read a [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). This question is off-topic on Code Review, and just got closed.

Comment: @holroy ok, i'm going to read it,... sorry for annoying :)

Comment: I've not used sqlalchemy my self, but maybe this link could help you on your way: http://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.org/en/0.8.0/api/entity.html

Answer (score 5):

There is a library called [SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach](https://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/) which provides a way to create entities having an image object. These could be exposed via some url.

Otherwise you can get a file object straight-forward via the `SingleImageSet` class.

With the lib you can choose from two of storages, such as the filesystem's or Amazon's S3. Inside the docs there is a [described example](https://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/guide/declare.html#object-type) (grey box) how to define previously the storage and then an User entity and owning a UserPicture entity.

```python
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_imageattach.entity import Image, image_attachment

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
"""User model."""

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)
    picture = image_attachment('UserPicture')
    __tablename__ = 'user'

class UserPicture(Base, Image):
    """User picture model."""

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship('User')
    __tablename__ = 'user_picture'
```

I don't know Flask, but perhaps you can use a filestorage via some wsgi declaration together with the Lib here. I hope it helps you a bit and gives you some **.

Answer (score 2):

I read in this post[1] that the best way is to declare the image field as a string to hold an url or link to the image, the image then can be stored in a external server, different from the server of your application. So if somebody have the same doubt just declare it as string and continue with your app development. A little disappointed of database management systems they only can be used to store numerical and alphabetical data(:p).

[1]https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/31tywp/afbest_way_to_store_avatars_images_etc/

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to hash your image files, you might want to replace LargeBinary with a string set as a specific amount of characters. You can then set an image value e.g

```
class User(Base):
        image = Column(string(int), nullable=True, 
temp='thepicture.jpg')
```

Assuming the picture is saved as `thepicture.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

You should never save large blobs of binary data (images etc.) to a database. Databases are not designed to work as file storage, so you will only destroy your database performance if you do that.

Like you already speculated, the better way is to save the files to disc and just store the image file name to database. The added benefit is that when your application grows larger, you can just store images to some disc server or cloud or whatever and all you web hosts can access the files from there.

If you want, you can figure out some good folder structure for your images, for example one folder for profile pics etc. But with modern filesystems it does not actually matter at all. After all, you don't probably need to manage those files by hand, so finding specific files from disks is not crucial.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that at some point you might want to server your static content (images, css, js files) from other server than the dynamic flask app. If you design your system right from the beginning with that idea in mind, the scaling will be easier in the future.